# Firebase jobdispatcher triggering job once

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm using firebase job dispatcher for making network calls lets say every 30 seconds, my service class:

```
 @Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters job) {
    getLocation();
    return true;
}
```

and my job instance:

```
 Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
            .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0,20))
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();
```

but the service is getting called only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For periodic jobs the minimum interval is 15 minutes from Nougat. Try with a larger time interval

Comment: thank you for pointing it out, also when api call goes phone wakes up, educate me when application is in running mode service calls will go or not?